# Fatal error with calendar module

Tags: views, datetime

I am a bit of a Drupal beginner (D7).

I used to get this error on some pages:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function set_display() on a non-object
>   in
>   /hsphere/local/home/ulufenci/test_directory/sites/all/modules/calendar/theme/theme.inc
>   on line 656

I went to check the incriminated file and identified that this has to do with the following function:

```
function theme_calendar_stripe_legend($vars) {
  if (empty($vars) || !$view = $vars['view']) {
    return '';
  }

  list($view_name, $display_id) = explode(':', $view);

  $view = views_get_view($view_name);
  $view->set_display($display_id);
  $row_options = $view->display_handler->get_option('row_options');

  // MORE COMMANDS
  }
```

where line 656 is the one using the set_display() function.

Yesterday, I uncheck an option to use overlay for the admin pages, and now I get it on EVERY admin page. (Which incidentally means that I cannot access any admin page, so can't do much at the moment.)

I don't really know what is going on, and would appreciate any help on how to debug this.

Thank you!!!

Comment: It makes me think that I tried to have a calendar view of some events that would add stripes to events depending on their taxonomy, but I can't check this hypothesis because I cannot access the admin pages... :/

Comment: I think the problem is the stripes used in the display. I would like to remove them. Problem: to do that, I would need to access the Views panel, but I can't if the Calendar module is enabled. If I disable it, then I can't access the fields I am supposed to access.